# Как узнать value нажатой кнопки

Tags: javascript

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var bt = document.getElementsByClassName("but");
    for (var i = 0; i < bt.length; i++) {
    bt[i].onclick= function strPad() {
      alert(bt[i].value);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button value="FILL_RIGHT" class="but" ">Справа</button>
<button value="FILL_LEFT" class="but" ">Слева</button> 
<button value="FILL_BOTH" class="but" ">И там , и там</button><br><br>
```

Я понимаю , что цикл `for` , в данном коде , просто переопределяет событие onclick у каждого полученного объекта в массиве . Подскажите , как узнать value именно у той кнопки , которая была нажата .
Код нужен чисто на `JS` , а не на `jQuery.`

Comment: На момент выполнения обработчика, `i` указывает на последнее значение. Замыкания используем, например.

Comment: за html следите, что у вас за кавычки после класса?

Comment: Не заметил) Случайно поставились ) В коде этого не было

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контекст, в котором вызывается обработчик, - кликнутый элемент.

```
bt[i].onclick = function() {
    alert(this.value);
};
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function strPad() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }

  var bt = document.getElementsByClassName("but");
  for (var i = 0; i < bt.length; i++) {
    bt[i].onclick = strPad;
  }
}
```

```html
<button value="FILL_RIGHT" class="but">Справа</button>
<button value="FILL_LEFT" class="but">Слева</button>
<button value="FILL_BOTH" class="but">И там , и там</button><br>
```

Comment: Спасибо , очень помогли

Comment: @AndrewKostyaevDestroer На здоровье. Успехов!